# Add extra field to group contact - relation

Tags: contacts, groups

Is it possible to add an extra field to the group contact relation ?

I have contacts grouped but in these groups they all have different functions.

**For example**:

```
User 1 connected to Group 1 - Function of user 1 in group 1 is "chairman"
User 1 connected to Group 2 - Function of user 1 in group 2 is "secretary"
```

Comment: To clarify, the question seems to be : Is it possible to define some contact functions in the context of a group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

On the custom fields page I've added a set of fields connected to "group".
I named these fields "chairman, secretary,etc.". I choose the contact reference fieldtype. So i can choose which user is chairman, etc.
All this info (group, groupmember, function) I can display in a view in Drupal.

Comment: Ok, so i guess i didn't understand you question. Glad you found a solution to your problem. You can mark your answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, in your example, you have 2 organizations contact called "Group 1" and "Group 2" and one individual contact called "User 1".

In that case, I can think of several way of doing what you want :

1. create different relationship type "Chairman", "Secretary", ... and use the proper relationship between the contacts. This way, you will see in the tab Relationship all the information you need
2. Have one type of relationship (e.g. Employee) and add the function in the description. The description is visible in the Relationship tab so it will give you a quick way to see the function but it is less obvious in a user experience point of view that description = function
3. Create a custom field "Function" on the Relationship type that you want. The drawback is that your custom field won't be visible from the Relationship tab without clicking on the "View" link for a particuliar relationship.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a organization contact type for the groups and then define relationships. E.g. group 1 is then a contact and chairman is a relationship between group 1 and an individual